# How to get a commit for committing it on another machine?

Tags: git

I have a repository. I want to apply its last commit to another repository on another machine. How can I retrieve the commit and apply it again?

Comment: You mean you want to `git format-patch` and `git am`? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-C:-Git-Commands-Email

Answer (score 0):

I would use `git diff`.

Example:

1. On your **source** repo : `git format-patch HEAD~` : this will generate a patch file with the a `0001` prefix and the beginning of your commit message followed by the `patch` suffix.
2. On the **destination** repo : `git apply PATH_TO_PATCH`